# How to automatically adjust textfields height to fill in a table cell?

Tags: longtable, height, textfield

I am making a document in which I am using a lot of tables which are using checkboxes and textfields.

Both are working fine only one issue I have and that is the automatic adjustment of the textfields height base on the text in other column of the table.

below I give an example of what I have developed.

```
    {\scriptsize{
    \begin{flushleft}
    {\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.25pc}
    \setlength\LTleft{0cm}
    \begin{longtable}[H]{!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}P{1.1cm}!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}p{9.1cm}!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}c!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}c!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}c!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}p{3.2cm}!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}} 
    
     \caption[MyCaption]{\footnotesize{ \textit{MyCaption\hfill\mbox{}}}}
    \arrayrulecolor{bleudefrance}
    \hline \rowcolor{bleudefrance}
      & & \multicolumn{3}{!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}c!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}}{\color{white} Result} &  \\  \cline{3-5}    %\hhline{--~~~-}
     \rowcolor{bleudefrance} 
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white} No.}    &   \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white} Checks}            & \cellcolor{bleudefrance} {\color{white}V}      & {\color{white}X}     &  {\color{white}-}       &     \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white} Note}\\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {\footnotesize{{\textit{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- \footnotesize{MyCaption\hfill\mbox{}}}}}} \\
    \hline \rowcolor{bleudefrance}   & & \multicolumn{3}{!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}c!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}}{\color{white} Result} &  \\  \cline{3-5}    %\hhline{--~~~-}
     \rowcolor{bleudefrance} 
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white} No.}    &   \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white} Checks}            & \cellcolor{bleudefrance} {\color{white}V}      & {\color{white}X}     &  {\color{white}-}       &     \multirow{-2}{*}{\color{white} Note}\\ \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{6}{!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}r!{\color{bleudefrance}\vrule}}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    
    \hline 
    \endlastfoot
    
   1.2.3   & \parbox{9cm}{\vspace{0.15cm} \blindtext
     \vspace{0.2cm}} &   \myCheckBox  &   \myCheckBox  &  \myCheckBox & \myTableTextFieldm{4.7cm}[120pt][3.25cm]{}[l] 

\end{longtable}}
\end{flushleft}}}
```

The code for \myTableTextFieldm is as below:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\myTableTextFieldm{m O{\tfh} O{\tfw} m O{l}}{\parbox{#1}{\vspace{0.1cm} \TextField[multiline, name==\romannumeral\fldn@me,charsize=\tfcs,bordercolor=\bcolor,height=#2,width=#3, default=#4, align=#5]{} \global\advance\fldn@me1 \vspace{0.1cm}}}
```

So in summary, my aim is to automatically adjust the height of the text field height (120pt above) in last column to the height of the \parbox I have in the second column. Please let me know if you have a solution to this.

I have a lot of tables like this and if I can do this automatically instead of manually it would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome! Please consider posting a complete self-contained MWE, this helps people here to help you much faster.

Comment: Apart from quite a number of missing packages, your example is also missing the definition of the color `bleudefrance`, the `P` column type and the `\myCheckBox` command. Apart from that, your code will still result in an error message due to a missing `\\ ` right after the caption.